# Building a resizable HTML layout

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="main" style="height: 100%">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="toolbar" style="height: 50px">
    </div>
</div>
```

So, `main` div is been resized, `toolbar` should have fixed height and `content`'s height should be = `height of main` - 50px. How is it possible to do so using styles only (without using JavaScript)?

Comment: You have phrased the question in such a way that there are only two possible answers. Yes or No.

Comment: I asked `How is it possible` but not `Is it possible`

Comment: He clearly asked, "How is it possible," and provided an example of what it should look like. Problem?

Comment: @DotNETNinja I'm not sure if you've noticed, but I've posted an answer. If it's not what you're looking for, could you please update your question?

Comment: @ShadowScripter, I've seen and +1d for great answer. Thank you. I'm in progress of checking it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What a mess, huh? Don't worry about it, your question was and still is valid. Let's just focus on answering the question.

I took the liberty of making three examples<sup>1</sup>:

- [one that looks like your first picture](http://jsfiddle.net/t7WtT/) (before all the edits)
- [one with the most recent edit](http://jsfiddle.net/L6Zeu/).
- [one that does the same thing, but horizontally](http://jsfiddle.net/AjmXh/1/)

Let's see if I can explain them properly.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Sadly, I couldn't make them resizable according to the new CSS3 property [`resize`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize).</sub>

---

### The explanation

So, I used an old technique where you basically use a wrapper with 100% height, then give it a negative margin and a positive padding corresponding to the constant height value. The combination of a negative margin and a positive padding will result in an empty space with the same height as the content with a fixed height.

```
.container{
    height: 400px;
}

.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.content{
    height: 100%;
}

.fixed_content{
    height: 50px;
}
```

Technically, the fixed content is being "pushed out" from the wrapper, but since the wrapper has a negative margin that adjusts for that element, it looks like normal flow.

To better demonstrate, I drew this picture.

[image: demonstration]

It should be noted that you can do the same thing horizontally as well, with some minor adjustments.

```
.container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.content{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.fixed_content{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In principle, it works the same way. The main difference is that you have to "force" the inline elements to stay on the same line, so that the overflow is instead horizontally aligned. I do that by using `white-space: no-wrap;` and `display: inline-block;`

Here is a picture I drew that demonstrate the horizontal equivalent.
[image: demonstration2]

The possibilities are endless! You can add more elements to it, as long as you know the sum of all the fixed elements height/widths.

- [Here's one with top and bottom toolbars as well as 2 50% height content elements](http://jsfiddle.net/L6Zeu/2/)
- [Here's one using both vertical and horizontal wrappers](http://jsfiddle.net/L6Zeu/3/).

Table layouts are for wimps. All the cool programmers use `div`s. ;)

---

### [First example](http://jsfiddle.net/t7WtT/) | Code

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='node_1'>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <div class='node_1_1'>
                <div class='wrapper_2'>
                    <div class='node_1_1_1'></div>
                    <div class='node_1_1_2'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='node_1_2'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px;
}

.container{
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.node_1{
    border: 2px solid gray;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    padding: 52px 0 0 0;
    margin-top: -52px;
    height: 100%;
}

.node_1_1{
    border: 2px solid purple;
    height: 100%;
}

.node_1_2{
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #b80808;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.wrapper_2{
    padding: 152px 0 0 0;
    margin-top: -152px;
    height: 100%;
}

.node_1_1_1{
    border: 2px solid green;
    height: 150px;
}

.node_1_1_2{
    border: 2px solid orange;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

---

### [Second example](http://jsfiddle.net/L6Zeu/) | Code

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="toolbar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px;
}

.container{
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 52px 0 0 0;
    margin-top: -52px;
}

#content{
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid green;
}

#toolbar{
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

---

### [Third example](http://jsfiddle.net/AjmXh/1/) | Code

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="vert-toolbar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px;
}

.container{
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 52px 0 0;
    margin: 0 -52px 0 0;
    white-space:nowrap; /*Force elements to stay on horizontal plane*/
}

#content{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
}

#vert-toolbar{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -2px; /*For the borders (2+2 = 4, -2 for a 2px "padding"*/

}
```