# create a scroll bar in a sidebar

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a scroll bar inside the #main div so that I can scroll that without scrolling the page or the title but it isn't working. What am I missing?

My code is as follows:

**CSS**

```
#topbar {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

#title {
    height:30px;
    background-color: red;
}

#main {
    height: auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="topbar">
    hello
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="title">
        title
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <!-- lots and lots of text-->
    </div>
</div>
```

You can find an example JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PTRCr/

Thanks

Comment: `overflow: scroll` in the sidebar and in main. You have `overflow: hidden`

Comment: but that scrolls the title with the main. I want to fix the title at the top

Comment: I understand; I neglected to read that. I would type what is in the answer below, but that is stealing.

Comment: Is that your code or you found ???

Comment: Do need really need a CSS solution?

Comment: @Starx, isn't a CSS solution better than js?

Comment: @dan, not in the cases where you have to analyse the existing markup.

Comment: @Starx, I'm not sure what you mean, I can change the html if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You're still on this project I see. There's also a lot of answers, but I see no one has made a working example of what I think you're asking for.

[Here's a working](http://jsfiddle.net/FWdPe/3/) example that (I hope) does what I think you're asking for.

I added content shifting wrappers so that the height can still be 100%. You can read more about that technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10092004/944301). I also removed all that absolute positioning, I see no reason why you should do that.

Each wrapper adjusts for the previous content, first the top bar with the height 40px and then the title with 30px.

This example should also follow your previous specifications, where the scrollbars will stay on the same baseline when resized.

[image: preview]

As you can see, by the code below, **it is possible to do a CSS only solution despite** what others have lead you to believe. It just takes a bit of tricks from the bag of CSS holding.

Man, I'm such a dork.

---

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FWdPe/3/) | Code

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id="top-bar">hello</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="side-bar">
            <div class="title">title</div>
            <div class="content_wrapper">
                <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur gravida interdum dignissim. Aenean quis neque diam, ac vehicula turpis. Vestibulum lacinia libero sed massa fringilla tempor. Donec dictum metus ac justo congue lacinia sit amet quis nisi. Nam sed dolor vitae nisi venenatis imperdiet ut ullamcorper sem. Maecenas ut enim in massa ultricies lacinia quis nec lorem. Etiam vel lacus purus, a placerat lectus. Ut sed justo eros. Curabitur consequat nisi ut diam lacinia at posuere purus tristique. Quisque eu dapibus nunc.</div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="side-bar">
            <div class="title">title</div>
            <div class="content_wrapper">
                <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur gravida interdum dignissim. Aenean quis neque diam, ac vehicula turpis. Vestibulum lacinia libero sed massa fringilla tempor. Donec dictum metus ac justo congue lacinia sit amet quis nisi. Nam sed dolor vitae nisi venenatis imperdiet ut ullamcorper sem. Maecenas ut enim in massa ultricies lacinia quis nec lorem. Etiam vel lacus purus, a placerat lectus. Ut sed justo eros. Curabitur consequat nisi ut diam lacinia at posuere purus tristique. Quisque eu dapibus nunc.</div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="side-bar">
            <div class="title">title</div>
            <div class="content_wrapper">
                <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur gravida interdum dignissim. Aenean quis neque diam, ac vehicula turpis. Vestibulum lacinia libero sed massa fringilla tempor. Donec dictum metus ac justo congue lacinia sit amet quis nisi. Nam sed dolor vitae nisi venenatis imperdiet ut ullamcorper sem. Maecenas ut enim in massa ultricies lacinia quis nec lorem. Etiam vel lacus purus, a placerat lectus. Ut sed justo eros. Curabitur consequat nisi ut diam lacinia at posuere purus tristique. Quisque eu dapibus nunc.</div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="side-bar">
            <div class="title">title</div>
            <div class="content_wrapper">
                <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur gravida interdum dignissim. Aenean quis neque diam, ac vehicula turpis. Vestibulum lacinia libero sed massa fringilla tempor. Donec dictum metus ac justo congue lacinia sit amet quis nisi. Nam sed dolor vitae nisi venenatis imperdiet ut ullamcorper sem. Maecenas ut enim in massa ultricies lacinia quis nec lorem. Etiam vel lacus purus, a placerat lectus. Ut sed justo eros. Curabitur consequat nisi ut diam lacinia at posuere purus tristique. Quisque eu dapibus nunc.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;          /* Normalization */
    padding: 0;         /* Normalization */
}

div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}

#top-bar{
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.side-bar {
    width: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid DarkOrchid;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.title {
    height:30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid salmon;
    background: red;
}

.wrapper{
    margin-top: -40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper > div{
    white-space: normal;
}

.content_wrapper{
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 100%;
}

.content{
    color: black;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I discovered after adapting this solution into my site that it doesn't work in IE7. When you go to your fiddle in IE7, all the sidebars are stacked vertically instead of horizontally. :(

Comment: @Barmar You're right. I don't like supporting IE7 or any of its other predecessors. If all web developers continue supporting them, they will never go away. This CSS trick doesn't work in IE7.

Comment: At least 7% of my customers use IE7. It's small, but not small enough to disenfranchise them. Luckily, I can check for IE7 and simply use the style sheet I developed before I discovered your code. I just need to refactor my style sheet to separate the parts that are specific to scrolling from the rest, so I can keep the rest in a common stylesheet.

Comment: @Barmar Most devs end up doing specific IE stylesheets, which makes it all so frustrating. I don't waste any time on it and do like [basecamp](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3097-developing-for-old-browsers-is-almost-a-thing-of-the-past) does and just message the user that they're using an inferior browser and need to upgrade. This is what all devs should do to ensure a better and standardized web.

Answer (score 1):

The element you want to be scrollable, should

- Have height and width defined
- have attribute `overflow:auto`

Example:

```
.scrollArea {
 width: 275px;
 height: 100px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 border-color: #6699CC;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 float: left;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: what if I don't know the height. I want the height to be the browser height - the title - the topbar. But I don't know the height of the browser of the title.

Answer (score 1):

CSS are stylesheet whose only purpose are to style document. They cannot investigate a pre-existing elements.

The only ways are whether the size of the div has to be fixed or you have to use some JavaScript to find out the exact height. The ways of which this can be done with CSS have already been presented by other users.

So, here is a way you can do using jQuery

```
$("#main").height($(document).innerHeight()-$("#title").outerHeight() - $("#topBar").outerHeight());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/PTRCr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In your case change CSS:

```
#sidebar {
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
bottom: 40px;
width: 80px;
overflow: scroll;   
}
```

Comment: is there a way to calculate the top automatically if I don't know the height of the title?

Comment: nop I don't think its done through css.But there is not any impossible in www world :) .

Comment: do you mean I have to use js to do it?

Comment: I'd rather use pure css if it's possible

Comment: @dan, How can a selector know the height of another element? It is not what CSS are for.

Comment: it shouldn't need to know the height of the other elements, I want it to go from the bottom of the element to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Dan, Explain me, how will an element go to the bottom, and fit perfectly unless it is fixed.

Comment: @Starx, I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `height` of the `<div id="main"` to show the scrollbar on it. whether you calculate it using javascript or jquery.

```
   #topbar {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    top: 40px;  
    bottom: 40px;
    width: auto;
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

#title {
    height:30px;
    background-color: red;
}

#main {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Check this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpcC6/15/).

Comment: the jsFiddle has the height set to 200px not 100%. I want it to fill to the bottom of the page. If you change it to 100%, the some of the div is hidden past the end of the page

Comment: set the height as per your requirement and now check the updated jsfiddle.

Comment: the updated js fiddle has the title scrolling with the main. I want just the main to scroll

Comment: updating jsfiddle just scrolling the main area only.. but you have to calculate the height of the main.. you must follow the css box model and positioning rules

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height for #main. It is working at http://jsfiddle.net/PTRCr/7/

```
#main {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: but I want it to go to the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if you know the height of your #title, in either `px` or as a percentage of its parent container

#title set in `px` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTRCr/16/)

```
#main {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px; /* set this to whatever you have set the height of #title to*/
    bottom:0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

#title set as % [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTRCr/17/) - Tested in IE/FF/Chrome